# Editorial Design: General recommendations for leading?

Tags: typography, typesetting, line-height

In the context of editorial design, by which I mean the type setting of running text; Is there a set of general recommendations for the amount of leading that should be applied in relation type size? (similar to Friedrich Forssman's recommendations for tracking in relation to type size)

Comment: In what context? This question is too broad as is IMO

Comment: @ZachSaucier In the context of editorial design, by which I mean the type setting of running text. I meant it as a broad question, simply wondering whether a set of default or recommended leading values exists (similar to Friedrich Forssman's recommendations for tracking in relation to type size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For body copy you should always have at least 1.2 times the font size although you could take it as far as 1.6 or so (I have a booklet document where I use 8/12).

Just make sure to try how your chosen font works under those settings since everything related to typesetting directly depends on what font are you working with.

Also keep in mind that paragraphs shouldn't be wider than 60 or 70 characters.

Answer (score 3):

The type size is just the virtual box the letters sit in. The vertical space a typefaces uses within that container can vary greatly. 
As a result, there can’t be a general recommendation for the line-height. It needs to fit the specific font, not a certain type size.